# JavaScript GUI library which is usable from ClojureScript?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, clojurescript

On one of my ongoing web development projects, we need to create a page (really a mini-application of its own) which will have an interactive, "Web 2.0" interface, more like a graphical desktop application than a typical web page.

I'm hoping to use a higher-level language which can compile down to JS for the client-side logic, rather than programming directly in JS, and ClojureScript is my first choice.

I'm looking for a JS GUI library which can be used from within ClojureScript, and which supports a style of programming similar to "desktop" GUI libraries like Swing, QT, wxWidgets, and so on. It should allow me to create popup `<div>` "windows", put widgets such as buttons/labels/etc. in them, attach event handlers to the widgets, and so on. Do you know of one which would work?

Comment: Man, I must be getting old if JavaScript is considered "too low level"!

Comment: Sarcasm aside, I'd recommend doing straight JavaScript in your position.  Since that's the base that everything compiles into, learn that well, and don't be dependent on some higher-level thing to hopefully do what you want.  Then learn the abstraction once you've mastered the fundamental.  Until you learn the fundamental, the abstraction is just some random other person/company getting in the way of what you really want to do, and what you really need to know.

Comment: @lobsterism, thanks for the advice, but I do know JS already, and I have good reasons for not wanting to write this app directly in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider Google Closure Library. It has all features you ask and is definitely usable from ClojuresScript, I've played around with it. See http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1430/docs/index.html

Comment: Hmm. It looks like Closure doesn't have layout managers... this seems like a major deficiency.

Comment: I am afraid no. It has a rich collection of all imaginable widgets, event handling etc, but you have to take care of the layout. I just use twitter bootstrap to place the <div>s, then closure widgets inside.

Comment: Really? I looked into Twitter Bootstrap a bit today, but didn't see anything for handling layout. Guess I'll have to look again...

Comment: Well, in bootstrap's documentation it is layout: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts.

Comment: Do you have to include *all* the CSS and JS for Bootstrap in order to take advantage of the layout features? (Always like to reduce the size of static assets...)

Comment: I just include all, there might be other ways. I don't really know a lot about bootstrap, I use it for basic layout and styling.

Comment: Instead of Bootstrap, you could use Skeleton -- it's minimalist and only does layout and some sensible style normalisations: http://www.getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 5):

Clojurescript is still young - I don't think there are mature frameworks of that caliber (yet?). Having said that, I'm building a UI using the following components:

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) + JQuery for visuals and UI elements
- [Chas Emerick's Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) for server-side authentication
- [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) + [Ring + Jetty](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring) for the server
- [Crate](https://github.com/ibdknox/crate) (Clojurescript [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup)) for html/dom generating
- [Jayq](https://github.com/ibdknox/jayq) for JQuery wrapping
- [Fetch](https://github.com/ibdknox/fetch) and/or [Shoreleave](https://github.com/ohpauleez/shoreleave)'s remotes for client-server RPC
- Shoreleave's pubsub mechanism or Clojure's `add-watch` for data binding

A good feature of Clojure and Clojurescript are that they favour simple functions on generic data structures. That's why you tend to see several smaller libraries that do one specific job, but work really well together, as opposed to giant monolithic frameworks with an object model that requires you to adopt one way of thinking completely.

Comment: +1. Right now I'm just interested in the client side, but thanks for the other info too. So you are using Hiccup on the client side to generate GUI elements dynamically? How about Fetch/Shoreleave? You are using those on *both* server and client side? I understand that there's no good way for a web server to push notifications to client-side JS, so do you have to poll? Or it's not required for your application?

Comment: I'm using Crate to dynamically generate html from hiccup-style data, and jayq (JQuery) to manipulate the DOM. I want to use Shoreleave's pubsub mechanism do declaratively hook up state (atoms), to functions, to other functions that render something in the DOM; this is all client-side, there's no pubsub remote stuff happening.

Comment: I looked into Twitter Bootstrap, but it doesn't allow a style of GUI programming anything like desktop GUI programming. It's still firmly in the "hack HTML/CSS by hand" camp, which is not where I want to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think ExtJS would fit the best in your case, even though this is pure JS. This is the most advanced web GUI library at the moment and it makes possible to create web applications the way similar the one using the desktop languages and IDEs. Just check out their [demos](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/). I don't think there will be something similar for the ClojureScript in the foreseen future.

Comment: I didn't expect to find a ClojureScript library -- that's why I asked for a JS library which can be *used* in ClojureScript. Thanks for your suggestion. I will evaluate it.

Comment: Hmm. I'm looking into ExtJS, but it seems to have a lot of disadvantages. ExtJS4 tries to be a whole application framework (including controllers, models, etc) which I don't want. I just want a GUI library. You have to purchase licenses to use it in a closed-source application. The quality of the examples and tutorials available is poor. The GUI widget demos look great, but they don't provide source code.